# Selecting simalar-looking items with HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql, duplicates

I have a form that makes widgets, if a user is trying to make a widget that's similar to one already in the database I'd like to let them know by showing them a list of possible duplicates.  However when I use `like` hibernate only selects exact matches.  How can I look through the database to see if any widget names are very similar to the one that's currently being made?  Thanks,

213897

Comment: What does your "LIKE" statement look like?

Comment: Be aware that LIKE is not about similarity, it is a simple regular expression operator. Unless you can identify a possible duplicate using a regular expression, it's not what you want.

Comment: I wasn't aware it used regex (I don't think it says that in the docs).  So I could do `/.*(<usersword>).*/ `with like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more a Lucene's kind of work... I think you can try Hibernate Search, which nicely integrates Hibernate (which you are already using) and index search like the one you would need.

Comment: I looked into that, but was unsure how to integrate it into our spring/hibernate project.  The manual has info on maven, but we're not using that.

Comment: Without maven I guess you have to figure out which jars you have to add; surely Hibernate Search, Lucene and their dependencies.
Once you figure that out there should be no other issue, you should be ready to go.

Comment: but how/where do I configure hibernate search?  the documentation references some xml <properties> but doesn't say where they go.  can I just start using it once it's in my project without any XML?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a similarity search engine (http://obsearch.net) with a distance function to achieve this. It depends on how you represent a "widget". Can you elaborate more on the properties that you consider relevant of a widget? (size color, or position, or just that it uses a similar number of components)

Comment: currently I'm just trying to match similar names.. but it would be nice to see if the new name shows up in other (in-the-database) descriptions, or if the descriptions are similar